# Calculate the mean values of individual rows, based the value of other columns and subtract from other rows

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

```
   Book_No  Replicate    Sample  Smell  Taste  Odour  Volatility                    Notes
0   12, 43          1   control    0.3   10.0     71           1                      NaN
1   12, 43          2   control    0.4    8.0     63           3                      NaN
2   12, 43          3   control    0.1    3.0     22           2                      NaN
3   19, 21          1   control    1.1    2.0     80           3                      NaN
4   19, 21          2   control    0.4    8.0      0           4                      NaN
5   19, 21          3   control    0.9    3.0      4           6                      NaN
6   19, 21          4   control    2.1    6.0     50           4                      NaN
7   11, 22          1   control    3.4    3.0     23           3                      NaN
8   12, 43          1  Sample A    1.1   11.2     75           7                      NaN
9   12, 43          2  Sample A    1.4    3.3     87           6  Temperature was too hot
10  12, 43          3  Sample A    0.7    7.4     91           5                      NaN
11  19, 21          1  Sample B    2.1    3.2     99           7                      NaN
12  19, 21          2  Sample B    2.2   11.3     76           8                      NaN
13  19, 21          3  Sample B    1.9    9.3     89           9     sample spilt by user
14  19, 21          1  Sample C    3.2    4.0    112          10                      NaN
15  19, 21          2  Sample C    2.1    5.0     96          15                      NaN
16  19, 21          3  Sample C    2.7    7.0    105          13             Was too cold
17  11, 22          1  Sample C    2.4    3.0    121          19                      NaN
```

I'd like to do two separate things. Firstly, I'd like to calculate the mean values for each 'smell', 'volatility', 'taste' and 'odour' columns of the 'Sample' Control, where the 'Book_No' is the same value. Then, subtract those mean values from the individual Sample A, Sample B and Sample C, where the 'Book_No' matches those of the control. The resulting dataframe should look something like this:

```
   Book_No  Replicate    Sample     Smell  Taste  Odour  Volatility                    Notes
0   12, 43          1   control  0.300000  10.00   71.0        1.00                      NaN
1   12, 43          2   control  0.400000   8.00   63.0        3.00                      NaN
2   12, 43          3   control  0.100000   3.00   22.0        2.00                      NaN
3   19, 21          1   control  1.100000   2.00   80.0        3.00                      NaN
4   19, 21          2   control  0.400000   8.00    0.0        4.00                      NaN
5   19, 21          3   control  0.900000   3.00    4.0        6.00                      NaN
6   19, 21          4   control  2.100000   6.00   50.0        4.00                      NaN
7   11, 22          1   control  3.400000   3.00   23.0        3.00                      NaN
8   12, 43          1  Sample A  0.833333   4.20   23.0        5.00                      NaN
9   12, 43          2  Sample A  1.133333  -3.70   35.0        4.00  Temperature was too hot
10  12, 43          3  Sample A  0.433333   0.40   39.0        3.00                      NaN
11  19, 21          1  Sample B  0.975000  -1.55   65.5        2.75                      NaN
12  19, 21          2  Sample B  1.075000   6.55   42.5        3.75                      NaN
13  19, 21          3  Sample B  0.775000   4.55   55.5        4.75     sample spilt by user
14  19, 21          1  Sample C -0.200000   1.00   89.0        7.00                      NaN
15  19, 21          2  Sample C -1.300000   2.00   73.0       12.00                      NaN
16  19, 21          3  Sample C -0.700000   4.00   82.0       10.00             Was too cold
17  11, 22          1  Sample C -1.000000   0.00   98.0       16.00                      NaN
```

I've tried the following codes, but neither seems to give me what I need, plus I'd need to copy and paste the code and change the column name for each column I'd like to apply it to:

```
df['Smell'] = df['Smell'] - df.groupby(['Book_No', 'Sample'])['Smell'].transform('mean')
```

and I've tried to apply a mask:

```
mask = df['Book_No'].unique()
df.loc[~mask, 'Smell'] = (df['Smell'] - df['Smell'].where(mask).groupby([df['Book_No'],df['Sample']]).transform('mean'))
```

Then, separately, I'd like to subtract the control values from the sample values, when the Book_No and replicate values match. The resulting dataframe should look something like this:

```
   Book_No  Replicate    Sample  Smell  Taste  Odour  Volatility               Unnamed: 7
0   12, 43          1   control    0.3   10.0     71           1                      NaN
1   12, 43          2   control    0.4    8.0     63           3                      NaN
2   12, 43          3   control    0.1    3.0     22           2                      NaN
3   19, 21          1   control    1.1    2.0     80           3                      NaN
4   19, 21          2   control    0.4    8.0      0           4                      NaN
5   19, 21          3   control    0.9    3.0      4           6                      NaN
6   19, 21          4   control    2.1    6.0     50           4                      NaN
7   11, 22          1   control    3.4    3.0     23           3                      NaN
8   12, 43          1  Sample A    0.8    1.2      4           6                      NaN
9   12, 43          2  Sample A    1.0   -4.7     24           3  Temperature was too hot
10  12, 43          3  Sample A    0.6    4.4     69           3                      NaN
11  19, 21          1  Sample B    1.0    1.2     19           4                      NaN
12  19, 21          2  Sample B    1.8    3.3     76           4                      NaN
13  19, 21          3  Sample B    1.0    6.3     85           3     sample spilt by user
14  19, 21          1  Sample C    2.1    2.0     32           7                      NaN
15  19, 21          2  Sample C    1.7   -3.0     96          11                      NaN
16  19, 21          3  Sample C    1.8    4.0    101           7             Was too cold
17  11, 22          1  Sample C   -1.0    0.0     98          16                      NaN
```

Could anyone kindly offer their assistance to help with these two scenarios?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Would it be helpful if `Book_No` were two separate columns as well?

Comment: I really don't have a preference! I was mainly looking at keeping the dataframe nice and tidy, but if you think two separate columns would help, then please go-ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting into different columns and reordering:

```
# This may be useful to you in the future, plus, ints are better than strings:
df[['Book', 'No']] = df.Book_No.str.split(', ', expand=True).astype(int)
cols = df.columns.tolist()
df = df[cols[-2:] + cols[1:-2]]
```

You should only focus on one problem at a time in your questions, so I'll help with the first part.

```
# Set some vars so we don't have to type these over and over:
cols = ['Smell', 'Volatility', 'Taste', 'Odour']
mask = df.Sample.eq('control')
group = ['Book', 'No']

# Find your control values:
ctrl_means = df[mask].groupby(group)[cols].mean()

# Apply your desired change:
df.loc[~mask, cols] = (df[~mask].groupby(group)[cols]
                                .apply(lambda x: x.sub(ctrl_means.loc[x.name])))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Book  No  Replicate    Sample     Smell  Taste  Odour  Volatility                    Notes
0     12  43          1   control  0.300000  10.00   71.0        1.00                      NaN
1     12  43          2   control  0.400000   8.00   63.0        3.00                      NaN
2     12  43          3   control  0.100000   3.00   22.0        2.00                      NaN
3     19  21          1   control  1.100000   2.00   80.0        3.00                      NaN
4     19  21          2   control  0.400000   8.00    0.0        4.00                      NaN
5     19  21          3   control  0.900000   3.00    4.0        6.00                      NaN
6     19  21          4   control  2.100000   6.00   50.0        4.00                      NaN
7     11  22          1   control  3.400000   3.00   23.0        3.00                      NaN
8     12  43          1  Sample A  0.833333   4.20   23.0        5.00                      NaN
9     12  43          2  Sample A  1.133333  -3.70   35.0        4.00  Temperature was too hot
10    12  43          3  Sample A  0.433333   0.40   39.0        3.00                      NaN
11    19  21          1  Sample B  0.975000  -1.55   65.5        2.75                      NaN
12    19  21          2  Sample B  1.075000   6.55   42.5        3.75                      NaN
13    19  21          3  Sample B  0.775000   4.55   55.5        4.75     sample spilt by user
14    19  21          1  Sample C  2.075000  -0.75   78.5        5.75                      NaN
15    19  21          2  Sample C  0.975000   0.25   62.5       10.75                      NaN
16    19  21          3  Sample C  1.575000   2.25   71.5        8.75             Was too cold
17    11  22          1  Sample C -1.000000   0.00   98.0       16.00                      NaN
```

Comment: Don't think that output is correct compared to the OP's output?

Comment: @JonClements pretty sure OP's output is just incorrect, it's only for `Book_No = '19, 21'` where lies the discrepancy.

Comment: @BeRT2me is correct, with the Sample C example I've gone wrong slightly in my (un)trusty Excel calculation to generate the example. And the coding seems to give the desired output. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

First we get the mean of the control samples:

```
cols = ['Smell', 'Taste', 'Odour', 'Volatility']
control_means = df[df.Sample.eq('control')].groupby(['Book_No'])[cols].mean()
```

Then subtract it from the remaining samples to get the fixed sample data. To utilize pandas automatic alignment, we need to temporarily set the index:

```
new_idx = ['Book_No', df.index]
fixed_samples = (df.set_index(new_idx).loc[df.set_index(new_idx).Sample.ne('control'), cols]
                 - control_means).droplevel(0)
```

Finally simply assign them back into the dataframe:

```
df.loc[df.Sample.ne('control'), cols] = fixed_samples
```

Result:

```
   Book_No  Replicate    Sample     Smell  Taste  Odour  Volatility                    Notes
0   12, 43          1   control  0.300000  10.00   71.0        1.00                      NaN
1   12, 43          2   control  0.400000   8.00   63.0        3.00                      NaN
2   12, 43          3   control  0.100000   3.00   22.0        2.00                      NaN
3   19, 21          1   control  1.100000   2.00   80.0        3.00                      NaN
4   19, 21          2   control  0.400000   8.00    0.0        4.00                      NaN
5   19, 21          3   control  0.900000   3.00    4.0        6.00                      NaN
6   19, 21          4   control  2.100000   6.00   50.0        4.00                      NaN
7   11, 22          1   control  3.400000   3.00   23.0        3.00                      NaN
8   12, 43          1  Sample A  0.833333   4.20   23.0        5.00                      NaN
9   12, 43          2  Sample A  1.133333  -3.70   35.0        4.00  Temperature was too hot
10  12, 43          3  Sample A  0.433333   0.40   39.0        3.00                      NaN
11  19, 21          1  Sample B  0.975000  -1.55   65.5        2.75                      NaN
12  19, 21          2  Sample B  1.075000   6.55   42.5        3.75                      NaN
13  19, 21          3  Sample B  0.775000   4.55   55.5        4.75     sample spilt by user
14  19, 21          1  Sample C  2.075000  -0.75   78.5        5.75                      NaN
15  19, 21          2  Sample C  0.975000   0.25   62.5       10.75                      NaN
16  19, 21          3  Sample C  1.575000   2.25   71.5        8.75             Was too cold
17  11, 22          1  Sample C -1.000000   0.00   98.0       16.00                      NaN
```

If you want you can squeeze it into a one-liner, but this his hardly comprehensible:

```
cols = ['Smell', 'Taste', 'Odour', 'Volatility']
new_idx = ['Book_No', df.index]

df.loc[df.Sample.ne('control'), cols] = (
    df.set_index(new_idx).loc[df.set_index(new_idx).Sample.ne('control'), cols]
    - df[df.Sample.eq('control')].groupby(['Book_No'])[cols].mean()
    ).droplevel(0)
```